# How to display an Excel with PhpSpreadsheet when loading the information with PHP

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

I am currently using the PHPSpreadsheet library to take values from PHP to Excel, what it does now is to take the values to an excel and store them in the address that I specify. but what I'm looking for is that when I upload information, show me the excel to open. When I used the PHPExcel if I could, and it was done with: $ objWriter-> save ('php: // output') then the excel was displayed to open. My code with PHPSpreadsheet is the following:

```
<?php 
require_once("vendor/autoload.php"); 

 use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
 use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

 $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
 $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
 $a="we";
 $a1="are";
 $a2="the";
 $a3="world"; 

  $sheet->setCellValue('A2', $a);
  $sheet->setCellValue('c2', $a1);
  $sheet->setCellValue('E2', $a2);
  $sheet->setCellValue('G2', $a3);

  $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
  $writer->save('C:\xampp\example.xlsx');

 ?>
```

Could it be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can't show a Excel file without an application for open it, I think you could use another web application for display the file on web browser.